# When condition in groupBy function of spark sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to apply if condition in groupBy operation of spark dataframe. If first condition is satisfied then select column "A" otherwise column "B" of given dataframe

It is easier to return single column to groupBy column condtion.

For ex

```
df.groupBy(when(col("name") === "a",col("city")).otherwise(col("country"))).agg(lit("Individual").alias("level")).show
```

Above code provides me result. But if i want to return multiple columns based on if condition then it is failing

My code:

```
val df = Seq(
  ("a", "abcdef", "123" ,"def", "uyhiu"),
  ("a", "7yjbb", "345" ,"hgh", "hjjhj"),
  ("d", "sbkbnn", "456","gyu", "hghj" )
).toDF("name", "email", "phone", "city", "country")

   val list1 = Array("phone", "city")
   val list2 = Array("phone", "country")

df.groupBy(when(col("name") === "a",list1.map(col): _*).otherwise(list2.map(col):_*)).agg(lit("Individual").alias("level")).show
```

But I am getting error:

> :52: error: no : _*' annotation allowed here (such
>   annotations are only allowed in arguments to *-parameters)
>          df.groupBy(when(col("name") === "a",list1.map(col): _*).otherwise(list2.map(col):_*)).agg(lit("Individual").alias("level")).show
>                                                            ^ :52: error: no : _*' annotation allowed here (such
>   annotations are only allowed in arguments to *-parameters)
>          df.groupBy(when(col("name") === "a",list1.map(col): _*).otherwise(list2.map(col):_*)).agg(lit("Individual").alias("level")).show

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply the `when` expression to both columns:

```
df.groupBy(
  when(col("name") === "a", col("phone")).otherwise(col("city")),
  when(col("name") === "a", col("phone")).otherwise(col("country"))
)
```

Of course, you can preconstruct these using some collection operations:

```
val names = Vector(("phone", "city"), ("phone", "country"))

val columns = names.map {
  case (ifTrue, ifFalse) =>
    when(col("name") === "a", col(ifTrue)).otherwise(col(ifFalse))
}

df.groupBy(columns: _*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me the approach you are using is incorrect. You can't change the column names of the groupBy clause dynamically for each and every record. It can be the result of some expression but not manipulating the column names itself. You can use filters and do a union later as below.

```
scala> val df = Seq(
     |   ("a", "abcdef", "123" ,"def", "uyhiu"),
     |   ("a", "7yjbb", "345" ,"hgh", "hjjhj"),
     |   ("d", "sbkbnn", "456","gyu", "hghj" )
     | ).toDF("name", "email", "phone", "city", "country")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, email: string ... 3 more fields]

scala>  val list1 = Array("phone", "city")
list1: Array[String] = Array(phone, city)

scala> val list2 = Array("phone", "country")
list2: Array[String] = Array(phone, country)

scala> val df1 = df.filter("name='a'").groupBy(list1.map(col(_)):_*).agg(lit("Individual").alias("level"))
df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [phone: string, city: string ... 1 more field]

scala> val df2 = df.filter("name!='a'").groupBy(list2.map(col(_)):_*).agg(lit("Individual").alias("level"))
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [phone: string, country: string ... 1 more field]

scala> df1.union(df2).show
+-----+----+----------+
|phone|city|     level|
+-----+----+----------+
|  345| hgh|Individual|
|  123| def|Individual|
|  456|hghj|Individual|
+-----+----+----------+


scala>
```